# Common LISP Using Equals Predicate in Cond

Tags: common-lisp

In Common LISP I am attempting to provide a list and create an array:

```
(defun make (hand)
  (make-array '(5 2) 
              :initial-contents
              hand))

(defparameter array(make '((3 H)(2 H)(11 D)(8 C)(5 D))))
```

This seems to work fine. Where I am tripping up is working with  this array.
I want to compare the 2nd field in each position of the array.

ie. 
H eq H? Yes.
H eq D? No. End.

I am unsure how to do this. I tried:

```
(cond ((eq 'aref hand 1 1) 'aref hand 0 1) (t)))
```

This did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`eq` takes two parameters:

```
(eq 'h 'h)
=> T
(eq 'h 'd)
=> NIL
```

`aref` takes a number of parameters, depending on the rank of the array- in your case, three:

```
(aref hand 1 1)
=> H
(aref hand 0 1)
=> H
```

What you want is to give the latter as arguments to the former:

```
(eq (aref hand 1 1) (aref hand 0 1))
=> T
```

`cond` allows you to check a set of conditions and return a value according to the first condition that is true: `(cond (condition-1 value-1) (condition-2 value-2) ...)`

```
(cond ((eq (aref hand 1 1) (aref hand 0 1))
       "first and second are the same")
      ((eq (aref hand 2 1) (aref hand 0 1))
       "first and third are the same")
      (t
       "this is always true"))
=> "first and second are the same"
```

Comment: @JT93: This is a solid answer to your question. Please accept the answer to show this is resolved. Please check Stackoverflow's faq to understand how this community works. I can guarantee that a small investment will get you a better response as time goes by.